# How saved CC payment method should work

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, payment-methods, payment-gateway

I need a explanation about using saved CC payment method. First of all, as I read Magento CE is not PCI compliant, so this method should not be used in live store using CE ?

I really cannot find a the full steps to be able of using this method. For example What I found is how to activate the method, then if the customer used this method you can find the card information to process the payment offline.

**What is and how is processing the payment offline done ?**

So when the admin get the card information, he should go to bank to take the money from the customer's account or is it using a payment gateway such as paypal or authorize ? called I have a explanation in details of the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that I should customize the CE to implement PCI compliant. And we cannot use the CC payment in CE version by default.

There are many options to handle the CC processing, depend on the service provider. For example some banking provided virtual terminal for online credit card processing

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2.1 API use is recommended for payment processing.

Storing card data means heavier re-assesment for simple design changes.

More info https://magento.com/resources/technical/pci-compliance